# Compiler clang.exe can't find the header on VSCode

Tags: compiler-errors, visual-studio-code, llvm-clang

I try to set the c_cpp_properties.json like this

(I have combine the header in the LLVM document)

```
{
        "configurations": [
            {
                "name": "Win32",
                "includePath": [
                    "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                    "H:\\LLVM\\include/**",
                    "H:\\LLVM\\x86_64-w64-mingw32\\include/**",
                    "H:\\mingw-w64\\mingw64\\include/**",
                    "H:\\mingw-w64\\mingw64\\x86_64-w64-mingw32/**"
                ],
                "defines": [
                    "_DEBUG",
                    "UNICODE",
                    "_UNICODE"
                ],
                "compilerPath": "H:/LLVM/bin/clang.exe",
                "cStandard": "c11",
                "cppStandard": "gnu++14",
                "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64"
            }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

but it always appear the error message when detect the

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <locale>

detect #include error. please update the includePath
```

However when I change the compiler to gcc.exe or g++.exe,

or delete the c_cpp_properties.json then it can work.

I try to delete the c_cpp_properties.json, C/C++ tool will auto change the

compiler to gcc.exe, then it also can work.

**My OS is Windows 10**

**LLVM and MinGW-w64 are the latest**

*Thanks for your help.*

Answer (score 0):

I find LLVM document have clang-cpp.exe,

if I used it to compile the c++ program it will run correct,

you can change the compiler from **C/C++ tool** when you want to

compile the **C++ program**.

**Otherwise you only can use clang.exe to compile the C program !!!**